# Reverse-engineer 3d animation float compression

Tags: animation, 3d, compression, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a game cutscene file and can't figure out compression used for object transform animation. Here's an example of compressed position:

Last 4 bytes on each line are correct coordinates in world space (little-endian float)

```
0080193C 2D4A2D38 588EAAC3 // X
00B819C0 D0EC4F38 75FB6945 // Z
00208DBD CF1ECF36 BEE35A43 // Y
```

Then goes animation itself, I figured that delta for each axis takes 2 bytes:

```
0000 72AC 2F24
3E03 06A8 0522
1504 19A8 1021
5004 37A8 E420
2704 19A8 4921
CD03 1EA8 0222
6203 FCA7 C622
EA02 F2A7 A923
6F02 E3A7 6024
...
```

Example of animation in an "idle" state without movement:

```
00D63CC0 BDD63C38 AB659244 003456C0 D6345638 86104D45 00000000 00000000 8C095043

FFFFFFFF0000 FFFFFFFF0000 FFFFFFFF0000 FFFFFFFF0000 FFFFFFFF0000 FFFFFFFF0000
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I decompress this? I would appreciate any help a lot. Thanks.